# Example of a stochastic process $X_t$ such that given condition holds

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

any thoughts on this?

Find a stochastic process $X_t$ such that it satisfies the following two conditions:

1. ms-$\lim_{t \to \infty} {X_t} = 0$
2. ms-$\lim_{t \to \infty} {X_t}^2 \neq 0$

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On $(0,1)$ with Lebesgue measure define $X_t(\omega)=t^{\frac 1 4} I_{(0,\frac 1 t)}(\omega)$. Then $EX_t^{2} \to 0$ but $EX_t^{4}=1$ for all $t$.

Comment: Oh, I think $X_t(\omega) = t^{\frac{1}{4}}W_t$, $W_t$ the Brownian motion works too.

Comment: $W_t$ has same distribution as $\sqrt t Y$ where $Y$ has standard normal distribution. So $EX_t^{4}=t^{3}EY^{4}$ which does not tend to $0$ as $ t \to \infty$.

Comment: Just to clarify, showing ms-$\lim_{t \to \infty} {X_t}^2 \neq 0$ is equivalent to showing $E\left[{X_t}^4\right]$ does not tend to $0$ right? If so, then wouldn't $X_t = t^{\frac{1}{4}}W_t$ be accepted since $E\left[{X_t}^4\right] = t^2E\left[Y^4\right]$.

Comment: I'm taking limit $t \to \infty$

Comment: In you example $EX_t^{2}=t^{3/2}$ which does not tend to $0$.

Comment: Ah yes, I made a mistake. I have a rough feeling that any stochastic process with a Brownian motion term would not be able to satisfy these 2 conditions...